Is there a simpler way of using file names as a value in a json file using a schema
I want to use file names as values to properties in a json file and have intellisense work on them.
Using the Blog Post Example from json-schema.
{ 
    "title": "New Blog Post", 
    "content": "This is the content of the blog post...", 
    "publishedDate": "2023-08-25T15:00:00Z", 
    "author": {
        "username": "authoruser",
        "email": "author@example.com"
    },
    "tags": ["Technology", "Programming"]
}

I want the allowed values of tags to be file names from a tags folder so in this case I'd have tags/Technology.json and tags/Programming.json and potentially show some information from the file like a description. As an example Technology.json might look something like.
{
    "name": "Technology (Modern)",
    "description": "Posts about technology created after the year 2000"
}

From what I've found it seems like I'd have to generate a schema file from those json files like
{
    "type": "array",
    "items": {
        "anyOf": [
            {
                "const": "Technology",
                "description": "Posts about technology created after the year 2000"
            },
            {
                "const": "Programming",
                "description": "Posts about any kind of programming"
            }
        ]
    },
    "uniqueItems": true
}

and use it as a $ref in tags of the schema I want to use it in.
Is there any simpler way of doing this that I'm missing? I know it's pretty simple already but I feel like I'm just overlooking something.
EDIT
I would have a file layout something like
posts/
  blog-post-1.json
  blog-post-2.json
  ...
tags/
  Technology.json
  Programming.json
  Retro-Technology.json
  ...

The blog posts' tag property would only accept values of the file names (minus extension) in the tags folder so in this case ["Technology", "Programming", "Retro-Technology", ...]. I'd also like it so that IntelliSense shows information about the tag like the description.
Is there a simpler way of doing this than generating an anyOf array from all the files in the tags folder like above?
The end goal is to have the blog post json get parsed by something and when it reaches tags it can just look in /tags/{tag_value}.json for the data it requires (e.g. an ID to create a URL to the tag page).

The filenames can be mapping keys like a dictionary using propertyNames with a pattern for your key. Then use additionalProperties with a schema to define the required schema
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
    "type": "object",
    "required": ["tags"],
    "properties": {
        "tags": {
            "type": "object",
            "propertyNames": {"pattern": ".json$"},
            "additionalProperties": {
                "$ref": "#/definitions/metadata"
            }
        }
    },
    "definitions": {
      "metadata": {
        "type": "object",
        "required": ["name", "description"],
        "properties": {
          "name": {"type": "string"},
          "description": {"type": "string"}
        }
      }
    }
}

{
    "tags": {
        "technology.json": {
          "name": "Technology (Modern)",
          "description": "Posts about technology created after the year 2000"
        },
        "programming.json": {
          "name": "Technology (Modern)",
          "description": "Posts about technology created after the year 2000"
        },
        "coding.json": {
          "name": "Technology (Modern)",
          "description": "Posts about technology created after the year 2000"
        },
        "crying.json": {
          "name": "Technology (Modern)",
          "description": "Posts about technology created after the year 2000"
        }
    }
}


Thanks, I'm not sure if I'm misunderstanding something or if it's because I worded my question badly, but this seems to be for creating a schema to validate the generated file which isn't what I'm trying to do. I've edited my question to try and explain what I'm trying to do a bit better.

This kind of thing is well out of scope for JSON Schema. I would suggest generating your schema using the files in your tags folder rather than hardcoding it, but other than that, there's not really anything else you can do to make this better.
